# Alternative ways to update apps via App Store

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, software-update

So I'm trying to update from Xcode 7.0.1 to Xcode 7.1 from the App Store. Xcode 7.1 is one of the my available updates. I use the latest EL Capitan 10.11.1. I click the UPDATE button for Xcode 7.1 it says "waiting" and PAUSE then a second later it goes back to UPDATE and nothing installs nothing updates, it's not telling me that I have something else open, which I don't. Is something wrong with App store now? Is there an alternative way to update my Mac apps?

Comment: does this happen with all of your apps or just Xcode ?

Comment: I only had this 1 update so I don't know.

Comment: you can download and install Xcode manually, http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1/Xcode_7.1.dmg you'll need to login with your developper account

Comment: I can't do that either, I tried but I keep receiving an error saying I can't open up Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I assume ou are using Xcode, and thus have it installed:
Look in the Appstore Purchased tab. If Xcode is in there: move Xcode from the Utilities folder to the Trash, do not empty the trash. Then on the Appstore Purchased tab click install Xcode, this will install the latest Xcode. When all ok empty the trash.